# None Exception rasied in try except block

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use a simple function:

```
def is_float(value):
    try:
        float(value) #float(value if value else "")
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

to check if an value is float or not.
Now, even though the check is in an try except block, this error is raised if the value is None:

```
2023-02-06 09:47:27,021 app - ERROR:Exception ....
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'.
```

Can someone explain why?
If you want to try it yourself, just execute the function with a None value and it will throw.

Comment: You are catching `ValueError`s but not `TypeError`s.

Comment: value might be None. you could try to use Exception instead of ValueError.

Comment: "Can someone explain why? If you want to try it yourself, just execute the function with a None value and it will throw." This sounds like you already understand what `None` is. So now I don't understand why you are confused. What do you think should happen instead when `float(None)` is attempted? Why? When you **read the error message**, and it tells you `float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'.`, what is confusing about that? You understand what strings and numbers are? You understand that `NoneType` is the type of `None`? You understand what an argument is?

Comment: just a heads up: that commented part `value if value else ""` will also fail. `float('')` throws an error as well; best to just return false at that point. Unless the value is an `0` which is also falsy.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel you don't need to be rude ;D
Just saw my mistake, that was pretty dumb ofc

Comment: No rudeness intended. I am genuinely trying to figure out **what the question is**. If it's easy for you to understand the problem with what you already know, then there isn't a question at all, and this should be closed as a typo.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The problem was that I just didn't see that I was using valuError instead of exception. 
I don't know why, I just didn't notice it and was very confused

Comment: Yes, that fits very neatly within what we consider "not reproducible or caused by a typo" here.

Comment: @rv.kvetch For what input would the commented version fail? (I'd write it as `float(value or '')`, btw.

Comment: It looks like it would just raise a ValueError for inputs of `0` and `None`. might be other values too, non-floats for example.

Comment: so might have misspoke, by fail i meant it would go directly to the `except` clause.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Ah, right, for `0` it would incorrectly report `False`. So yeah, best purely trust `float` to determine what works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option #1**: Use `Exception` clause (broadest) instead to handle the `None` type.

```py
def is_float(value):
    try:
        float(value)
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False
```

**Option #2**: `except` the errors that you expect.

```
def is_float(value):
    try:
        float(value)
        return True
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        return False
```

Tests:

```
assert is_float(1.2)
assert is_float(3)
assert is_float(0)
assert not is_float(None)
```

Comment: np! glad that you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ah okay, nvm, I just saw my mistake.

```
except Exception as e:
```

would be what I wanted.
That was silly.